# Computing file HASH returns different values

Tags: .net, hash, sha512

Does anybody know, why the following code returns different results on some machines?

```
Private Shared Function ComputeHashValue(ByVal Data As String) As String
    Dim HashAlgorithm As SHA512 = SHA512.Create
    Dim HashValue() As Byte = HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data))
    ' Looping over the array and ANDing each byte with 0111111
    For i As Integer = 0 To HashValue.Length - 1
        HashValue(i) = HashValue(i) And Convert.ToByte(127)
    Next
    Return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(HashValue)
End Function

Private Shared Function AreByteArraysEqual(ByVal array1 As Byte(), ByVal array2 As Byte()) As Boolean
    If array1.Length <> array2.Length Then Return False
    For i As Integer = 0 To array1.Length - 1
        If array1(i) <> array2(i) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function

Private Shared Sub SomeMethod()
    Dim t_prvBytes() As Byte = New Byte() {SOME VALUES} 'Previously computed HASH
    Dim t_dllStream As New IO.FileStream("C:\myfile.txt", IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)

    Dim t_reader As New IO.StreamReader(t_dllStream)

    Dim t_dllHash() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ComputeHashValue(t_reader.ReadToEnd))

    MsgBox(AreByteArraysEqual(t_dllHash, t_prvBytes))

    t_dllStream.Close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shouldn't be converting the hash into text via `Encoding.ASCII`. It's *not* ASCII text. (It's not text at all.) You're also hashing the result of ASCII-encoding the original text, which you read in using `Encoding.Unicode`. Why?

You're doing all kinds of conversions between text and binary forms - and you probably shouldn't be doing *any*. Just hash the binary data (using [`HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19.aspx)), and keep the result in binary too. If you *really* need to convert the binary data into text, use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx).

In addition, you're comparing the data with a previously computed value - but you haven't explained where that previously computed value came from to start with.